# Pyomo AttributeError Constraint

Tags: pyomo

I have a simple model:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import numpy as np
import csv
 
Nmax = 10
def up_constraint(model,n,t):       
    s = model.a[t] + model.b
    return sum(model.imp[n,t]-model.exp[n,t]  for n in model.N) <= s 

def build_model(N,T,Tup):            
    
    model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
    # Define the parameters
    
    model.N = pyo.Set(initialize=N)
    model.T = pyo.Set(initialize=T)
    model.Tup = pyo.Set(initialize=Tup)

    # Parameters
    model.a = np.ones(Nmax) * 1.5    
    model.b = 10
    # Decision variables
    model.imp = pyo.Var(model.N,model.T)
    model.up   = pyo.Constraint(model.N,model.Tup,rule= up_constraint)  
    return model
```

But when I call build_model:

```
N = np.array([n for n in range(0,10)])
T = np.array([t for t in range(0,96)])
Tup = np.array([t for t in range(56,80)])

build_model(N,T,Tup)

ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint up with
    index (0, 56): AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute
    'is_expression_type'
```

Comment: There are several problems with the code that you have, but it isn't totally clear how you got to that error with the code provided.  Can you edit your post to include enough information to run your code and produce the error?  Specifically, add the imports and representative examples of `N, T, Tup, Tdown` to produce the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple things biting at you here...

At the root of the error you mention is a problem with your `numpy.ones` array.  You are passing it `N` which is a list of numbers (more below).  The first number in the list is 0, so you are creating a multi-dimensional array with a zero size first index.  Example:

```
In [30]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                             

In [31]: N = np.array([t for t in range(3)])                                                                                                                                                            

In [32]: X = np.ones(N)                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [33]: X.shape                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[33]: (0, 1, 2)

In [34]: len(X)                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[34]: 0
```

**Advice:**  Forget about `numpy` when getting started with these models.  It is not useful.  Just use python lists, sets, dictionaries.

Several other things "need some love" while you have the hood up.

You seem to be treating `N` as both a fixed value and an array, which is leading to the problem above.

You are creating `model.a` to be an array of the same value.  Why not make it non-indexed?  And you are indexing it with `t` in your constraint, where I think you mean `n`.  Just make it a singleton.
**Advice:**  use `pyo.Param` to construct these things and if you need to print your model, it is much easier to troubleshoot.

You are passing `n` to the constraint construction, but not using it as you are providing `n in model.N` within the function

Comment me back if you are still stuck!  Good luck!

Comment: @gdm I'm not sure how to do that.  Is there a follow-up question of some kind?